# Migration from WAS 8.5.5 to WAS 9 Liberty Server

Tags: web, java-8, websphere-8, java-6

I have been working with migrations of applications from WAS 8.5.5 to WAS 9 Liberty Server. Is there anyone who can confirm what requirements must be met?
My application is built in Java 6 - what kind of other technologies do I need for migration?

Comment: Its impossible to know how to migrate a web app without knowing anything about it.

Comment: what kind of info you need ? so I can provide that.

Comment: To migrate you'll need to know what libraries you use, what configuration you use, what database you use, what other services you use, etc.

Answer (score 1):

IBM provides a [collection of articles](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/websphere-migration-knowledge-collection-migrating-liberty) that talk about the basics of migrating applications to Liberty. These pages include links to tools meant to scan the environment and identify the changes needed to make applications compatible with Liberty and produce sample server configuration.

I'd suggest you read through these and see if they answer your basic questions, and then you can post more specific questions if you need to.